# Use an extension method for a projection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is it possible to use an extension method for a projection in Entity Framework:

```
public class ProjectRepository
{
    public IQueryable<ProjectDto> GetActiveProjects()
    {
        // db.Projects is a DbSet<Project>
        // i want to use a projection to convert it to ProjectDto,
        // I know I can do new ProjectDto but I would rather do an
        // extension method and abstract that logic out
        return from p in db.Projects
            where p.Status == "Active"
            select p.AsProjectDto();
    }
}
```

Right now I get the following error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'AsProjectDto' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

LINQ to SQL seems to be able to handle this, but Entity Framework does not. Is there a certain way I need to write the extension method so it works in EF?

This is my extension method:

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{
    public static ProjectDto AsProjectDto(this Project project)
    {
        return new ProjectDto
        {
            Id = project.Id,
            Name = project.ProjectName
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of AsProjectDto?

Comment: Updated with the extension method

Comment: then would you not have `select ProjectExtensions.AsProjectDto(p)`?

Comment: @DiskJunky No...it is an extension method.

Comment: @Dismissile apologies, it seems that my understanding of the fundmentals of the question is lacking - suggestion withdrawn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call a C# method on the data to project it, you'll need to convert to a Linq to Objects query for that part;

```
return (from p in db.Projects
        where p.Status == "Active"
        select p)
    .AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.AsProjectDto());
```

This will do the data selection from the database, and return the data as an Enumerable on which you can do the projection.

EDIT: Can't test it with EF right now, but since you asked, you should be able to use an expression to do it in the database just as well;

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<Project, ProjectDto>> AsProjectDto = 
    x => new ProjectDto {Id = x.Id, Name = x.ProjectName};

return db.Projects.Where(p => p.Status == "Active").Select(AsProjectDto);
```

Comment: gah! 3 seconds too late....this is the reason it doesn't work for you; because L2E cannot translate your method into SQL.

Comment: @StephenByrne I understand that, but is there a way to write it that it can understand it (without Linq to Objects), using expressions, etc.

Comment: @Dismissile Added a simple but (with EF) untested way of doing it with an expression.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That will do just as well.